# Gcloud hyperparameter tuning returning strings instead of integers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, gcloud, hyperparameters

I'm attempting to run a gcloud ml-engine training job with hyperparameter optimization. In the gcloud command line I point to a config.yaml containing my hyperparameters to be tuned, and these are labeled as "type: INTEGER". However, I get an error during the training job indicating that the values are being returned as a string rather than integer.

The error occurs the first time the program attempts to substitute a hyperparameter's variable with its value for that particular trial.

Specifically, it is returning '140' instead of 140 for SEQ_LEN, a variable that points to args.seq_len.

```
Command '['python', '-m', u'trainer.task', u'--learning-rate', u'0.0015826983878389717', u'--num-layers', u'9', u'--num-epochs', u'20', u'--scale-factor', u'0.4453220449907912', u'--third-layer-size', u'259', u'--first-layer-size', u'209', u'--train-batch-size', u'43', u'--second-layer-size', u'194', u'--seq-len', u'140', '--job-dir', 'gs://ben-lstm-test/models/LTCUSD___BTCUSD_ETHUSD_BCHUSD/2']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

What am I doing wrong here? The command line appears to have been subjected to a re.split or something. Is that related?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake. The seq-len argument in ArgumentParser was missing "type=int". Problem solved.